# How do I unjam a Hasselblad 500 C/M body when the lens was removed uncocked?

Tags: lens, repair, body, medium-format, hasselblad

I've recently been learning how to use a Hasselblad 500 C/M. Foolishly, I removed the lens in an uncocked state, causing the lens and body to become out of sync. Through YouTube videos, I have figured out how to recock the lens.

However, I have seen no videos or pictures showing how to unjam the body of the Hasselblad. I understand that I must turn the screw directly on the inside of the body. Do I turn it clockwise or anti-clockwise? A video or photo would be much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't turning the film advance crank do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can buy the way over priced tool or use a dime. look at the top right of the image. turn the winding crank if it does not look like the image.

[image]

Comment: This is clear on how to properly cock the lens, but clear as mud on how to line up the body if it is out of line.